# Google OAuth check if user logged out from Google

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

After user being logged in with Google OAuth - is it possible to check if later user get logged out from Google?

**Scenario:**

1. User logged in in `Google`
2. User logged in on `mysite.com` using `Google OAuth`, and login state **stored in session for 1 year**.
3. User logged out from `Google`, but forgot to log out from `mysite.com`
4. After **one week** someone stoled user's laptop. Thief won't be able to use `Google` but will be able to re-use logged in user session on `mysite.com`

**I wonder what are the ways to prevent such situation?**

I don't want to put this burden on user - log out him from `mysite.com` and ask to log in again every day.

Would like instead use **something automatic** like:

- When you logged in with Google OAuth you get some sort of ID
- Every day you validate that that original session is still active, by calling something like

`google.com/api/is-original-session-still-active?id=ID`

Comment: there is no such thing as being logged out from Open authentication.   If you are logging your user in with Oauth2 then you have an access token good for one hour and a refresh token good for as long as the user grants you access to their data.    oauth2 != openid connect

Comment: @DaImTo thanks. So, if user will be logged out from Google - the refresh token would stop working? Otherwise I don't see how refresh token could help to solve the problem. I need to know when user gets logged out from Google from SAME Browser, not when he revokes the access.

Comment: Oauth2 access is granted to your application independent of the user.  If a user logs out of their google account the refresh token will continue to work.  Google is not going to tell you if the user logs out of their account.  The two have nothing to do with each other.   Even if you are using openid connect to sign a user into your application google is not going to tell you if the user logged out of their account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: I suspect that you have your terminology incorrect i suspect you are using [Openid connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) and not [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) to sign-in your users.  However i will answer this question based upon Oauth2 as that's what you say you are using.*

**Oauth2**

Oauth2 is used to grant an application access to a users data.  When using an oauth2 token you are acting on behalf of the user.  There is in fact no user interaction when using Oauth2 tokens.

If a user consents to your application accessing their data you will get an access token and a refresh token.  Access tokens are good for an hour.  Refresh tokens are long lived and will give you access to a users data for as long as the user doesnt remove your consent and that you use it at least every six months.

As Oauth2 is without user interaction there is no way to use it to see if a user is logged into their account.   There is actually no Google api that would give you this information.   This would IMO be considered privet user information and not something that google should be sharing with third party applications.

**Suggestions**

You may want to consider some changes to your application.

1. implement logout everywhere. If the user changes their password then all of the devices they have logged in should automatically need to be re-authenticated.
2. Your sessions should be good for only a week or two and you should enable sliding.
3. Tell your users to remove the consent of your application to their data this will also force them to have to relogin.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to know about user account security events that could impact users of your app if your app is using Sign In With Google, consider registering your app to receive events for [Cross Account Protection](https://developers.google.com/identity/risc).